# Unsupervised patterns finding in multidimensional time series data

Tags: time-series, clustering, sequential-pattern-mining

I have a problem where I have multidimensional time series data (e.g. 3 dimensions from accelerometer) and I need to find some patterns in the data. I might now approximately the possible duration of patterns and might be the number of different patterns. Other details (e.g. patterns shape, etc.) I don't know.

Just an example what I need to do is the following (here is just 1d data for simplicity):[image]

So, basically, I need to find an algorithm that would say that here are 2 clusters (or patterns) and here they are.

Answer (score 2):

See

Toeplitz Inverse Covariance-Based Clustering of Multivariate Time Series Data. D. Hallac, S. Vare, S. Boyd, J. Leskovec. ACM SIGKDD International Conference on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining (KDD), 2017. Best paper runner-up.

http://www.kdd.org/kdd2017/papers/view/toeplitz-inverse-covariance-based-clustering-of-multivariate-time-series-da

The code is available on

http://cs.stanford.edu/~jure/